# Spring Security - Login Form - GWT - Anchor tags

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I am trying to redirect Spring Security to a custom login page which GWT based. Here is my configuration:

```
<security:http pattern="/Main.html?#login" security="none" />

<security:http auto-config="true">
      <security:form-login login-page='/Main.html?#login' />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
</security:http>
```

From the spring security debug logs - it seems that the framework drops everything after the "#". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to fix this.  Spring security runs on server side,  and data in url after hash are never sent to the server from browser. Normally you would make a separate page for login, outside of your primary GWT application.

Comment: The problem is that - My GWT app has just one page Main.html and I want a login module to be loaded in that page before anything else is loaded. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: put login page outside of GWT app to the separate page, if you want to use spring security. Or simply don't define any security rules over Main.html. There is no real harm if some one will be able to download client JS code, as long as services will be secured with spring.

Comment: But I need to design a login page/widget using GWT. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes sure it is possible. Just create a separate GWT application. And try to keep it's size as low as possible

Comment: But how will that widget be part of current GWT application (Main.html)?

Comment: Why should it? Login is needed only to authenticate users. Create new GWT app, which will have only login related object, put it on separate page Login.html. When user is successfully authenticated redirect him to Main.html.

Comment: If these are two separate apps - how would spring security of Main.html determine if the user is authenticated?

Comment: Because you will have two *GWT* apps running in on single web app. You will have separate GWT applications but they are going to be using the same webapp, same HttpSession. From Login.html you'll send a request to the server to authenticate user. Spring will mark user as authorized, and user will be able to view Main.html.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere you can point to which shows how to run two GWT apps in a single web app?

Comment: I don't know of any examples, since it is pretty obvious.  You'll need to have to seprate entry points, GWT modules and host pages. I'd recommend to carefully read official GWT documentation. GWT app is basically a javascript. If you know how to include to different javascripts on two different pages, you should be able to do the same with GWT.

Comment: I think the better way is to create separate login page not in GWT, as jusio offered. I use this approach and it works fine. Is it necessary to create login page with GWT? I think not. You can simply create it using JS.Do not waste your app with making 2 GWT projects.

Comment: Using GWT for the login page is sort of mandatory for me. I finally ended up creating a Login.html as separate GWT module and integrated it will my original app. Thanks for all the help!